# Adding maven module with sources as another module

Tags: java, maven

I have a java maven project that has another module as a dependency.

That dependency has "-sources.jar" in the repository (and I can download the sources with `mvn dependency:sources`)

I now need to do some little one-line changes in the module I am using as a dependency. The ideal way would be to somehow copy this dependency as another module, with all its current sub-dependencies. Then when I build the whole project, I want to build my newly copied dependency and use it instead of the current dependency. (I hope it's clear what I want to do.)

However, I don't know at all how to do that, and if it's even possible.

edit:

To be clearer.

I have my own project. I am also using let's say `com.example.dependency` from a repository. There are however small bugs in the `com.example.dependency` module, so I want to download the source to me and fix it locally and use it as a submodule.

edit2:

I will add that the dependency is not any public project on github, etc. It is a module in a private maven repository that only I have an access to. I cannot clone the source control project. I can only use maven, and its dependency tracking, and the "dependency:sources" thing.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear what you mean...it sounds like you need a branch in your version control?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, it's not about my branch or my version control. I need to edit code *of the dependency*. I will try to rewrite my question, thanks for the feedback

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to fork the original dependency and mark it with an appropriate version to show that you have changed something.

Comment: OK. Is it possible to do it through maven? (I don't have access to the dependency version control. I only have access to the maven repository, that has "-sources.jar" in it.)

Answer (score 1):

what you may to to do is to checkout your dependency source as new project and do the changes. Then modify your project version and do the

> mvn install

to install it in your local repository, then you this version in your project as one of the dependency, you will add this dependency in usual way you have done earlier, but change the version to new version you have installed.

Comment: "what you may to to do is to checkout your dependency source as new project and do the changes." - OK, how to do that? I don't have access to the actual source like git repo etc, all I have is the maven repository, with the "-sources.jar" thing.

Comment: you have un jar (unzip) '-source.jar'. then create the new project from that source. ideally there will be pom.xml file. if not you have to create a one.

Comment: I don't see any pom.xml in the "sources.jar" file. I need it though to track the sub-dependencies of the modules (I don't know how exactly Maven does that.)

Comment: ok. in that case your best bet is to create a simple pom (jar) and do the maven install. you may have to manually add the dependency one by one for that project. this will be time consuming, but i dont see any other easy way to my knowledge

Comment: Ah, ok. I was under the impression that it might be easier than that :(

Comment: Oh, but there is a pom file next to the sources.jar thing (not in it). So that might actually help.